# Update iOS app without taking release from App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way to fix bugs or add a new feature to already published iOS app without going through entire release process?
The new changes should be reflected on app launch.
Similar to **CodePush** in `React Native`. As it becomes easier to fix live bugs and the users will not be affected further.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible when you are making changes to the javascript code only, which means if you are not touching native iOS code, you can use service like CodePush
https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push.

This will help you to publish a new version of js Bundle. The new bundle will be automatically updated in the app whenever there is a new version available.

EDIT:

To update Native iOS Code, you can use https://rollout.io/blog/updating-apps-without-app-store/

Comment: Yes right!!!. I want to know is there a way to change native iOS code on the fly

Comment: Hey Aniket, i think you can use some third party sdk for this purpose. For instance i found out this => https://rollout.io/blog/updating-apps-without-app-store/